# M2.4.2 | Credit Memo multistore returning with an mysql exception over xdebug

Tags: magento2, php

I have been debugging this issue for a while, I am getting this error when I am trying to create a credit memo for any order:

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a space added to the entity_type which is used to formulate the query to the DB, and this can be debugged & traced by adding breakpoints to the following file `Magento\SalesSequence\Model\ResourceModel\Meta line 87`

What I figured, the query was like this:

```
SELECT meta_id FROM sales_sequence_meta WHERE entity_type = 'creditmemo' AND store_id =1;
```

When I ran this query in my DB, I was getting no result, and the query was failing when I used to issue a credit memo from the Magento backend, eventually, I checked from the ***entity_type*** and the store_id in that particular table and the end result was the ***entity_type*** had an extra space like **'creditmemo  '**, and that what made it fail.

I hope it helps someone in need with a similar issue.